# Smooth login without javascript

Tags: php, html, authentication

**What i want:** clicking on login / pressing on enter will validate the login and redirect if correct (without javascript).

**What i tried:**

1. A form with a submit button and validating on an other php page **PROBLEM:** if login is not correct, i don't want to redirect and display an error message instead.

> ```
> <form action="loginServerside.php" method='POST'>
> ```

2. A form with a submit button and validating when the submit button is set.
   **PROBLEM:** submit button reloads page and then redirects if login was correct

> ```
> <form method='POST'>
>       <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
>       <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
>       <input type="submit" name='login' value="LOGIN" id="login" class="button"/>
> </form>
> if (isset($_POST['login']))
>      /*validate*/
> ```

3. Trying to prevent the page reload by using an input type="button" **PROBLEM:** the isset only works for submit buttons

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: You need a page reload to run server side code (PHP). Javascript runs client side so there you can run code without reloading the page.

Comment: but what happens when javascript is disabled...

Comment: Users that have disabled JS have chosen page reloads instead of js action.

Comment: You can run the login in an `iframe`...? Not many choices.

Answer (score 1):

For a login to take place, the client (browser) has to POST to the server and then receive a response. If you want that response to be something other than a full-page reload, you will need javascript in order to fetch JSON, or a page fragment via AJAX, or a signal over websockets, or a data channel through WebRTC or some other mode of full-duplex communication not in any way supported by normal request flow standards.

If it's just a matter of keeping something on the screen through that page reload, look up iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run server-side code (login credentials validation, in this case) without reloading the page. This requires AJAX, which involves Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, You want to validate the users input without a page reload or refresh, Doing this without client side scripts is as far as i know Impossible. Once PHP (Pre Hypertext Processor) has finished playing with your code its then sent to the client and PHP "Goes to sleep" until another page is loaded. Javascript is the best way to achieve your desired result. This isnt really an answer i guess but what your trying to do is act upon data that has not been sent to the server using only a server side technology. It is not possible.

Javascript can be a pain in the rear but there are tools out there now that make debuging simple Chrome even has a dev console built in that takes sme of the pain out of it.

Answer (score -2):

Check this tutorial... It has everything you need.

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html
Query the db for the count of results for the post values - If value is 1 login is success, else     displays the error message

```
if( $count==1 ){
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
  session_register("email");
  session_register("password"); 
  header("location:[name_of_your_success_page.php");
}
else {
  echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```